# Report ticks till intercept in Netlogo

Tags: report

How could I measure in Netlogo the number of ticks it takes for the 2 turtles to be aligned so that I can display that number in a monitor. I think that I have to use a to-report function, but I am not sure how I would measure the number of ticks it would take for the 2 turtles to be aligned.

The Netlogo code:

```
    turtles-own                         ; creates the following variables for each turtle:
[
  flock?                            ; turns on the flocking behaviour
]

to setup
  clear-all                         ; remove all turtles and reset environment
  reset-ticks                       ; set time (ticks) to zero

                                    ; start positions and angles of the intercepting agent
  let startXAgnt1 (list -10 -10 0 10 3)
  let startYAgnt1 (list -10 18 0 -10 8)
  let startDirAgnt1 (list 90 90 140 90 -90)

  create-turtles 1                  ; create intercepting turtle
  [
    set color red
    set size 1.5
                                    ; set location and angle according to scenario
    setxy item (scenario - 1) startXAgnt1 item (scenario - 1) startYAgnt1
    set heading item (scenario - 1) startDirAgnt1
    set flock? true                 ; agent tries to align or atract
  ]
  create-turtles 1                  ; create stoic agent representing the flock
  [
    set color blue
    set size 1.5
    setxy -20 -20                   ; same location and angle in each scenario
    set heading 45
    set flock? false                ; agent just travels in a straight line and avoids others
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles with [flock?]         ; only the intercepting turtle flocks
  [
    flock                           ; flock function calculates the heading based on align and avoid
  ]
  ask turtles
  [
    fd 0.2                          ; go forward by 0.2
  ]
  tick                              ; advance model time with one tick
end

to flock
  let otherTurtle min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]

                                    ; if other turtle is too close, avoid
  ifelse [distance myself < 1] of otherTurtle
  [
   face otherTurtle
    rt 180
   ]
  [                                 ; align if close and turtle wants to form a flock
    ifelse [distance myself <= 2] of otherTurtle
    [
      rt subtract-headings [heading] of otherTurtle heading
    ]
    [                               ; attract if in view and turtle wants to form a flock
      if [distance myself <= 20] of otherTurtle
      [
        face otherTurtle
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi! First of all, it is good, that you shared all of your code. However, it could be reduced to the relavant parts and edited, so that it runs without any input via console (except for adding a setup and go button).
What exactly are you struggeling with and what have you tried so far? In case, you don't know, how to get the number of ticks, there is the reporter `ticks` that reports the current value of the tick counter (see Netlogo dictionary https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will reduce it. I wanted to measure how many ticks it would take for both agents to be aligned. I did it manually, but I was wondering how to do it through a function. I added a monitor that displayed the ticks, but then I only saw the total amount of ticks and then manually stopped the model when the turtles were aligned, but now I want to have a function do that for me

Comment: So is your question about:
 1. how to measure if turtles are aligned inside the flock procedure?
 2. how to create a reporter for the monitor?
 or 3. how to stop the model?

Comment: My question is how to measure the amount of ticks it takes so that the turtles are aligned. I wanted to display that in a monitor

Answer (score 0):

1. measure if turtles are aligned inside the flock procedure:

```
if heading = [heading] of otherTurtle [...]
```

2. create a global variable to be reported and set it to "Not aligned" in the setup:

```
globals
[
  align_report
]
...
to setup
set align_report "Not aligned"
```

3. create a reporter for the monitor, that reports a global variable:

```
to-report get_ticks_if_aligned
  report align_report
end
```

4. change the value of `align_report`, when the turtles align for the first time inside the flock procedure:

```
  if align_report = "Not aligned" and heading = [heading] of otherTurtle
  [
    set align_report ticks
  ]
```

5. stop the model, when the turtles are aligned by adding the following to the go procedure before `tick`:

```
if align_report != "Not aligned" [stop]
```

So the code should look like this:

```
turtles-own                         ; creates the following variables for each turtle:
[
  flock?                            ; turns on the flocking behaviour
]
globals
[
  align_report
]

to setup
  clear-all                         ; remove all turtles and reset environment
  reset-ticks                       ; set time (ticks) to zero
  set align_report "Not aligned"

  create-turtles 1                  ; create intercepting turtle
  [
    set color red
    set size 1.5
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set flock? true                 ; agent tries to align or atract
  ]
  create-turtles 1                  ; create stoic agent representing the flock
  [
    set color blue
    set size 1.5
    setxy -20 -20                   ; same location and angle in each scenario
    set heading 45
    set flock? false                ; agent just travels in a straight line and avoids others
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles with [flock?]         ; only the intercepting turtle flocks
  [
    flock                           ; flock function calculates the heading based on align and avoid
  ]
  ask turtles
  [
    fd 0.2                          ; go forward by 0.2
  ]
  tick                              ; advance model time with one tick
end

to flock
  let otherTurtle min-one-of other turtles [distance myself]

                                    ; if other turtle is too close, avoid
  ifelse [distance myself < 1] of otherTurtle
  [
   face otherTurtle
    rt 180
   ]
  [                                 ; align if close and turtle wants to form a flock
    ifelse [distance myself <= 2] of otherTurtle
    [
      rt subtract-headings [heading] of otherTurtle heading
    ]
    [                               ; attract if in view and turtle wants to form a flock
      if [distance myself <= 20] of otherTurtle
      [
        face otherTurtle
        fd 0.35                      ;added strategy, which gives a result of the red turtle intercepting
      ]
    ]
  ]
  if align_report = "Not aligned" and heading = [heading] of otherTurtle
  [
    set align_report ticks
  ]
end

to-report get_ticks_if_aligned
  report align_report
end
```

Comment: That indeed works. Thanks a lot, Lena!